Ubuntu 22 host, Mac OS guest running in qemu: copy/paste from ubuntu <--> Mac os not working
I am running mac os sequioa guest VM on Ubuntu 22 host using this command:
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name macos-big-sur,process=macos-big-sur \
-machine q35,hpet=off,smm=off,vmport=off,accel=kvm \
-global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard \
-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 \
-device isa-applesmc,osk=ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal\(c\)AppleComputerInc \
-global nec-usb-xhci.msi=off \
-cpu host,-pdpe1gb,+hypervisor \
-smp cores=1,threads=2,sockets=1 \
-m 8G \
-device virtio-balloon \
-rtc base=localtime,clock=host,driftfix=slew \
-pidfile macos-big-sur/macos-big-sur.pid \
-vga none \
-device VGA,xres=1600,yres=900,vgamem_mb=256 \
-display spice-app \
-spice disable-ticketing=on,port=5930,addr=127.0.0.1 \
-device virtio-serial-pci \
-chardev socket,id=agent0,path=macos-big-sur/macos-big-sur-agent.sock,server=on,wait=off \
-device virtserialport,chardev=agent0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=vdagent0,name=vdagent \
-device virtserialport,chardev=vdagent0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
-chardev spiceport,id=webdav0,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 \
-device virtserialport,chardev=webdav0,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 \
-device virtio-rng-pci,rng=rng0 \
-object rng-random,id=rng0,filename=/dev/urandom \
-device nec-usb-xhci,id=spicepass \
-chardev spicevmc,id=usbredirchardev1,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=usbredirchardev1,id=usbredirdev1 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=usbredirchardev2,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=usbredirchardev2,id=usbredirdev2 \
-chardev spicevmc,id=usbredirchardev3,name=usbredir \
-device usb-redir,chardev=usbredirchardev3,id=usbredirdev3 \
-device pci-ohci,id=smartpass \
-device usb-ccid \
-chardev spicevmc,id=ccid,name=smartcard \
-device ccid-card-passthru,chardev=ccid \
-device qemu-xhci,id=input \
-device usb-kbd,bus=input.0 \
-k en-us \
-device usb-tablet,bus=input.0 \
-audiodev spice,id=audio0 \
-device intel-hda \
-device hda-micro,audiodev=audio0 \
-device virtio-net,netdev=nic \
-netdev user,hostname=macos-big-sur,hostfwd=tcp::22220-:22,id=nic \
-global driver=cfi.pflash01,property=secure,value=on \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file=macos-big-sur/OVMF_CODE.fd,readonly=on \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,file=macos-big-sur/OVMF_VARS-1920x1080.fd \
-device ahci,id=ahci \
-device ide-hd,bus=ahci.0,drive=BootLoader,bootindex=0 \
-drive id=BootLoader,if=none,format=qcow2,file=macos-big-sur/OpenCore.qcow2 \
-device virtio-blk-pci,drive=SystemDisk \
-drive id=SystemDisk,if=none,format=qcow2,file=macos-big-sur/disk.qcow2 \
-fsdev local,id=fsdev0,path=/home/vikas/Public,security_model=mapped-xattr \
-device virtio-9p-pci,fsdev=fsdev0,mount_tag=Public-vikas \
-monitor unix:macos-big-sur/macos-big-sur-monitor.socket,server,nowait \
-serial unix:macos-big-sur/macos-big-sur-serial.socket,server,nowait \
-machine accel=kvm

Is it possible to get copy/paste working from/to the ubuntu host to/from the mac os guest?
Thank you!
